# How Can i Load External page dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, css

http://etchapps.com/

The above site is example of what i am asking exactly.
When we click the navigation menu( like team,about ) it loads content dynamically.
Please tell me how to ahecive this
Thanks

Comment: Hi to all, actually i am new to development....that's why i asked....why you put nagative (-) against my ?

Comment: Anyway ,Thanks to all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asking for a bit much with this question, so I'm just going to suggest maybe exploring jquery-pjax as a pre-made solution: https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax

Comment: Thank you so much jack, can i have any example please